# How to add more probing points on the CR Touch

Tags: creality-ender-3

I have an Ender 3v2 and I recently installed the CR Touch auto bed leveler. I was wondering how to add more probing points.

Comment: Are you running the stock firmware, upgraded firmware, or custom firmware, i.e. Jyers UI?

Comment: You will need to compile you own version of the firmware.  Teaching tech has a detailed video describing the entire process for beginners (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9vxJT5Tgh4) and then another one (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neS7lB7fCww&t=792s) for the BLTouch modifications for Marlin. Take care, his wiring diagrams make assumptions based on other videos he has made.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like the number of points in each axis of the probing grid is defined by these lines:

```
#define GRID_MAX_POINTS_X 3    // Don't use more than 7 points per axis, implementation limited.
#define GRID_MAX_POINTS_Y GRID_MAX_POINTS_X
```

in Marlin's [Configuration.h](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/bugfix-2.1.x/Marlin/Configuration.h) file. So assuming you'd want the same number of points in each direction, change the `3` to another value less than or equal to `7`, and recompile Marlin.